# Regex translation for grunt

Tags: regex

Could someone please translate the following regex:

`/(([ \t]*)\/\/\s*bower:*(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/\/\s*endbower)/gi`

I'm presuming its something like

`/* bower:
endbower */`

Comment: What do you mean by translate?

Answer (score 0):

After a little digging around I found what I needed.

```
// bower:scss
// endbower
```

I appreciate my question was not very clear